# What is the maximum items that can be added to a map in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We have created a table named "user", with the field "books" as a map with a "Type" as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    books map<text, frozen<book>>,
    issued frozen<map<text, boolean>>,
    createdat timestamp,
    lastmodified timestamp
);


CREATE TYPE book (
    number uuid,
    name text,
    lastmodified timestamp
);
```

The "issued" field's data type is "map" with a Boolean value.

In cassandra tutorial it is written that "The maximum number of keys for a map collection is 65,535.".
Does it mean that we can add only 65535 keys in the "issued" field?.

The "books" field is a map with book "type". Whether the max key limitation is applicable for maps with a "type" also.
Or we can add any number of keys in "type". ie Can we add more than 65535 keys in "books" field?

While checking it with a database, we were able to add more that 150k records under the field "books", which could not be explained.

In the above 'user' table how many 'book' type data can be inserted to the 'books' field?

Answer (score 1):

"it depends", your limited to 65535 keys in issued yes, but theres practical limits too. The entirety of the map must be read off disk and brought into memory when read so its very expensive to read when theres a lot. A better alternative is actually to create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_books (
   id uuid,
   title text,
   value book,
   PRIMARY KEY ((id), title)
)
```

where the title of the book is the clustering key, then you can fetch all books by a user in a single efficient read and the driver can page through the result if it's too large. You also then do not have to worry about 64k limit.

Another alternative is like:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id uuid,
    user_created timestamp STATIC,
    user_last_modified timestamp STATIC,
    title text,
    book_number uuid,
    book_name text,
    book_last_modified timestamp,
    issued boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), title)
);
```

You would have for each user id a created/last modified in static row and then each book would be ordered by title (or book id or something). Thats assuming both issued/books had same key. That way you can read/update everything in single table and you wont have the collection limitations and performance impacts.